# Delete single doctrine entry by ID in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to set up a blog and I have a list of all blog entries as well as a list of all users for that blog. The admin of the blog has the possibility to delete single entries from these lists.
Anyway, I have the problem that when selecting one entry to be deleted, it's always the first entry in my list which gets deleted and not the one I actually selected.

Here's my deleteAction:

```
  /**
    * @Route("/blog/delete/{id}", name="entrydelete", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0})
    *
    */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Blog $blog) {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $entry = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:Blog')->find($blog);
      if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') || $entry->getAuthor() == $this->getUser()->getUsername() ) {
          $em->remove($entry);
          $em->flush();
          return $this->render('BlogBundle:blog:deletesubmit.html.twig');
        }
      else {
        return $this->render('BlogBundle:blog:error.html.twig');
      }
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
      $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'BlogBundle\Entity\Blog'
      ]);
    }
```

and the according twig template:

```
{% for blog in bloglist %}
  <h4>{{ blog.title }}</h4>
    <p><span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> Posted on {{ blog.date|date('d.M Y H:i A') }} </p>
    <p><span class="fa fa-user-circle"></span> Posted by {{ blog.author }} </p>
    <p>{{ blog.text }}</p>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-info">
        <a href="{{ path('entryedit', {'id':blog.id}) }}" style="color: #FEFEFE">Edit entry</a>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-warning">
        <a href= "#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" style="color: #FEFEFE">Delete entry</a>
      </button>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure?</h3>
              </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Do you really want to delete this profile?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Go Back
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-warning">
                    <a href="{{ path('entrydelete', {'id':blog.id}) }}" style="color: #FEFEFE">Yes</a>
                  </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <hr>
  {% endfor %}
```

So just to clarify this: If I have a list like that:
1. Entry 1
2. Entry 2
3. Entry 3
and I want to delete Entry 3, select that one and confirm, Entry 1 is gone.

Would be happy about any kind of help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a problem with your HTML code. You render as many modals as you have elements as your modal rendering is inside the `{% for %}` loop.

Apart from the fact that it is not really optimized to render so many modal elements, they all have the same `myModal` id. When you click on the "Delete entry" button, the modal with id `myModal` is shown, but there are 3 of them. Your browser shows the first one, that is why it is always Entry 1 which gets deleted.

There are other things that could be fixed and optimized in your code, but to answer your question, here is a simple fix.

Change this line:

```
<a href= "#myModal" role="button" ...>Delete entry</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="#deleteEntryModal{{ blog.id }}" role="button" ...>Delete entry</a>
```

And this line:

```
<div id="myModal" ...>
```

to

```
<div id="deleteEntryModal{{ blog.id }}" ...>
```

That way, you get a unique id for each modal element, which makes your page work and HTML valid too.

As I said before, several optimizations could be made too (like using only one modal element (out of the `{% for %}` loop), and changing the URL to delete the element with JavaScript. But that is out of the scope of this message.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that solved my problem perfectly! I'm open for any optimizations I could add, so feel free to share them with me if it's not too much of an effort for you!

Comment: Glad it helped! Some optimizations could be about code styling among others. I will try to add that to my answer and let you know.

Comment: @sonja I reformatted some of your controller's code on this page (comments at the bottom of the page): https://gist.github.com/michaelperrin/4771f2857fadfd43e2af6487efd986fa

Answer (score 1):

try to change this:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Blog $blog) {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $entry = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:Blog')->find($blog);
```

to this:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id) {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $entry = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:Blog')->find($id);
```

Because you need to find your entity by the id passed into the url, you aren't passed a Blog object but an id

Answer (score 0):

if entity manager can find a Blog object with an integer id also can find with `Blog $id`. point is $blog should be $id, because in routing you defined it `:id`

change this part:

```
/**
* @Route("/blog/delete/{id}", name="entrydelete", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0})
*
*/ 
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Blog $blog)
```

to

```
/**
* @Route("/blog/delete/{id}", name="entrydelete", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
*
*/
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Blog $id)
```